# How to find RowIndex in table

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am using the following JavaScript to get rowindex within a `tr` element, please suggest. I am stuck in this code. Thanks in advance.

```
<script>
  function jsmethod(a)
  {
    var row = document.getElementById("trHead");
    alert(row.children[0].rowIndex);
  }
</script>


<tr id='trHead' onclick='jsmethod(this);'>        
  <td> <a href='#' >Select</a></td> 
  <td>{$row['ecode']}</td> <td> echo $row[0];</td>
  <td>{$row['first_name']} {$row['middle_name']} {$row['last_name']}</td>             
  <td>{$row['father_name']}</td> <td>{$row['mother_name']}</td>
  <td>{$row['number_of_dependents']}</td> <td>{$row['dob']}</td>
  <td>{$row['gender']}</td> <td>{$row['identification_mark']}</td>
  <td>{$row['marital_status']}</td> <td>{$row['spouse_name']}</td>
  <td>{$row['mobile_number']}</td> <td>{$row['email_id']}</td>
  <td>{$row['adhar_id']}</td>  <td>{$row['pan_number']}</td>
  <td>{$row['passport_number']}</td> <td>{$row['tin_number']}</td>
  <td>{$row['dl_number']}</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are already passing `tr` to method so you can directly use `tr` to find `index`.

```
function jsmethod(tr)
{
   alert(tr.rowIndex);
}
```